# Object and Ternary Operator PHP

Tags: php, object

I wanna make use of the Ternary Operator with an object.

```
if($msg == 'hello'){
    $o->setHello('hello');
else
    $o->setHello('bye');
```

How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
($msg == 'hello') ? $o->setHello('hello') : $o->setHello('bye');
```

Answer (score 23):

```
$o->setHello($msg == 'hello' ? 'hello' : 'bye');
```

Answer (score 9):

How about?

```
$o->setHello($msg == 'hello' ? 'hello' : 'bye');
```